# How to make partition by some range of values in window function

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table for example:

Table `log`:

```
userId | action |           time       |
---------------------------------------|
  1    |    1   |   2020-11-27 05:48:02|
---------------------------------------|
  1    |    2   |   2020-11-27 05:49:02|
---------------------------------------|
  1    |    3   |   2020-11-27 05:50:02|
---------------------------------------|
  1    |    1   |   2020-11-27 06:49:02|
---------------------------------------|
  1    |    2   |   2020-11-27 06:50:02|
---------------------------------------|
  1    |    3   |   2020-11-27 05:51:02|
---------------------------------------|
  2    |    1   |   2020-11-27 05:49:02|
---------------------------------------|
  2    |    2   |   2020-11-27 05:50:02|
---------------------------------------|
  2    |    3   |   2020-11-27 05:51:02|
---------------------------------------
```

action `1` - marks that session is started

action `3` - marks that session is finished

How I can add a column and set some sessionId for each session?
Target table should have such a view:

```
userId | action |           time       | sessionId |
---------------------------------------------------|
  1    |    1   |   2020-11-27 05:48:02| SessionId1|
---------------------------------------------------|
  1    |    2   |   2020-11-27 05:49:02| SessionId1|
---------------------------------------------------|
  1    |    3   |   2020-11-27 05:50:02| SessionId1|
---------------------------------------------------|
  1    |    1   |   2020-11-27 06:49:02| SessionId2|
---------------------------------------------------|
  1    |    2   |   2020-11-27 06:50:02| SessionId2|
---------------------------------------------------|
  1    |    3   |   2020-11-27 05:51:02| SessionId2|
---------------------------------------------------|
  2    |    1   |   2020-11-27 05:49:02| SessionId3|
---------------------------------------------------|
  2    |    2   |   2020-11-27 05:50:02| SessionId3|
---------------------------------------------------|
  2    |    3   |   2020-11-27 05:51:02| SessionId3|
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here; please only use tags related to the question and technology you are using. You'll need to retag your RBMS.

Comment: Sorry for that @Larnu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a cumulative sum of the "1"s, I think:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when action = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by userid,time) as sessionid
from t
```